# Search for text between 2 strings multiple times on the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have run into a little bit of trouble where I need to search for the text between to different strings. I am pulling it from a URL where everything is pasted in one line.

What I am searching for is multiple IPs in the document (which are on the same line). The full strings in which I would like to search for look like this:

```
"ip_str": "0.0.0.0"}
```

So basically I would like to find the text between `"ip_str": "` and `"}`

Also would it be possible to save all of them to an output text document?

Comment: Any chance what you're getting back is JSON? In which case, use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: I'm trying to just use python as it's the only coding language we are allowed to use for 1st year of software development.

Comment: And I'm suggesting you use Python to parse the JSON - please go and *actually read* the link.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that was a link, thank you and ill check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could get away with string splitting:

```
data = open('input.txt').read()
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
parts = data.split('"ip_str": "')
for part in parts[1:]:
    part_cleaned = part.split('"}')[0]
    fout.write(part_cleaned + '\n')
```

It's quick-and-dirty but if you write and run this only once I think it's good enough. Using python's json module would be cleaner.